# Filter on Einstein Analytics Dashboard in lightning page returns no result

Tags: lightning, einstein-analytics, analytics, filters, einstein

**Description:**

Einstein Analytics dashboards integrated into Lightning Pages with filters, come with 'Modified' and '+X filters' buttons on top. In the case below we have 15 Filters applied.
[image: 15 Filters]

15 Filters represents 15 attribute fields which are single select picklists, and some of these fields are optional.

**Problem:**

Problem arises when an attribute is not selected and has the value "". In this case the filter on the analytics dashboard, returns no results since the comparison is either over 'in' or 'matches'.

See the examples below:

[image: 3 filters on 2 attributes with values selected, 1 attribute with no value selected]
~ ~ ~
[image: 2 filters on 2 attributes with values selected]
~ ~ ~
[image: 1 filter on 1 attribute with value selected]

**Question:**

No selection = Nature element ??
When there is no attribute value selected, we expect to see all possible values on the dashboard. Currently we are wondering if there is any reliable workaround or a reasonable solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case regarding this issue, after many messages and checks with internal  development teams, here is the answer from Salesforce support.

> We had a discussion regarding this internally and we would like to
>   confirm this point here that this particular scenario is more of a
>   limitation with regards to the product and not a bug.
>
> The Product team has agreed to take it on board in the future, however
>   as of now the filters are strictly applied and expect the field to be
>   available.
>
> We can work with the team internally to update the documents to
>   reflect this in a more better way for the customers as of now.
>
> So we would like to conclude here by saying that we do not consider
>   this as a bug inside Salesforce as of now and this is more of a
>   limitation from the products perspective.

I believe this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use coleasce() function. so that when no selection is made a default selection which you mention will be shown.

Comment: I use the filter field in the 'edit page' when I embed the einstein analytics dashboard into the lightning page, there I use json code such as:

{'datasets':{'getDataset':[{'fields':['customObject.fieldName'], 'filter':{'operator': 'in', 'values':['$fieldName']}}]}}

what do you mean with coleasce() function?

Comment: you have embedded the dashboard perfectly and nothing needs to be done in the lightning component. now navigate to analytics studio and open the embedded dashboard. go to the first chart step(no results found chart) and in the measure add Colesce() function. if your measure is count .then you need to generate 0 as count  from other dataset or same dataset and union it .

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks @Komal I am gonna give it a try.